# Shared Memory (Linux)

Tags: c#, linux, memory-mapped-files

I have some data in my shared memory. I can check it with ipcs.

```bash
root@A11XCN:/tmp# ipcs

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00002712 0          root       644        2696       2
0x0000283c 229377     root       644        788        0
```

The Question is, how can I access the key `0x00002712` in C# and read it as a stream? In C, I can do it with mmap() but I did not found any solution for C#.

Comment: [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)